# Can I still use the old TestFlight service for testing versions of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, udid

It isn't clear to me whether or not the old TestFlight service can still be used for testing iOS apps. I've seen a lot of information from various places about iTunes Connect, external users, internal users, limitations, etc, but nothing about the old service.

Do I *have* to go through iTunes Connect to test early versions of my app or can I use the old TestFlight service where I provisioned devices using the UDID? One of the reasons I ask is because of Apple's TestFlight app that was recently released that only supports iOS8 - our device target is iOS7 and below so it doesn't seem we can even utilize that service.

Comment: I used the old Test Flight service up through the launch of iOS 8. I don't see why it can't still be used. Of course the old fashioned AdHoc deployment still works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Yes, it is possible to still use the [old TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) instead of [Apple's TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/). *However,* to use the old TestFlight, you need to have already signed up for an account before they partially shut down.</strike>

*Apple has officially [shut down the old TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/update/).*

<strike>If you don't have an account, yet still want the freedom of the old TestFlight,</strike> you might try testing out [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/), however it does cost money.

Comment: Thank you. We already signed up for TestFlight and have been members for a few years now. Good to know this is still a viable option, at least in the short term.

Comment: HockeyApp is not free.

Comment: @ruslan Yes, it does cost money, as I stated in the answer. 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I decided to ask guys from [TestFlightApp.com](http://testflightapp.com). I hope their response helps you.

> You can continue to use TestFlightAppl.com. Please note that TestFlightApp.com and the TestFlight app in the Apple Store are separate services. Accounts and apps aren't shared between the two services.
>
> TestFlight betas from TestFlightApp.com can only be installed via the TestFlight webclip/bookmark or through www.testflightapp.com. The TestFlight App that's in the Apple Store is for the new TestFlight service on iTunes Connect (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/).

So yes, you can continue using TestFlightApp.com

Answer (score 1):

The 'old' Testflight service tesflightapp.com is closing down on the 26th Feb 2015. This is what Apple announced on 27th Jan:

> With the new version of the TestFlight service available inside of
>   iTunes Connect, we are also informing you that TestFlightapp.com will
>   no longer be available as of 2/26/2015.
>
> To prepare for the TestFlightapp.com closure, we recommend that you
>   export all of your current testers so you can import them directly
>   into the new TestFlight Beta Testing service.
>
> How to export testers from TestFlightapp.com
>
> 1. Sign in to the TestFlight Dashboard at testflightapp.com
> 2. Navigate to the "People" tab
> 3. Check mark the teammates you would like to export
> 4. Open the "Actions" menu on the right side of the teammates list
> 5. Select "Export Contact Info" to download the exported CSV file
>
> How to import testers into the new TestFlight Beta Testing
>
> 1. Sign in to iTunes Connect at itunesconnect.apple.com
> 2. Click "My Apps"
> 3. Select the app you want to enable for beta testing
> 4. Enter the "Prerelease" tab and select "External Testers"
> 5. Click the plus sign to add new external testers
> 6. Use the "Import File" from the "Add New External Testers" page to upload the exported CSV file